# How to do conditional formatting for a table based on values in separate columns?

Tags: google-sheets, custom-formatting

I have a table that I am trying to have each row highlight based on a blank cell in one column AND a value in another column. I want each row to look for a blank cell in column K and a value of 10 in column C. Long form explanation is: If the cell in column K is blank, AND the cell in column C is 10, then highlight that entire row.

This is what I could come up with but it highlights random rows so I know it's off: =AND($K2="",$C2="10")

I'm also unsure what to select for that range, I selected the entire table

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share a sample sheet to verify the range that you have selected? [Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IYrxGIHy8sIG0LATRF0TeR_4gkuNEGwm5V453S2waPI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It requires access. Please share your sample sheet with view permission to anyone with the link

Comment: Sorry about that, should be done now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

**Range:** `A1:O`

**Custom Formula:**

`=AND($K1="",VALUE($C1)=10)` or `=AND($K1="",$C1="10")`

### Output:

[image]

> Not sure why, but your Column C value was eveluated as a text and not a number. To make some workarounds, I used [VALUE()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094220) to convert text/string to a number first before comparing.
>
> Please make sure not to remove `$` in the formula. It is important to lock the columns to K and C and just increment the row number. If the `$` is not included, conditional formatting will loop all rows and columns in the given range

### Note:

The reason why your formula failed initially because it doesn't match with your range. Since your range started at Row 1, your formula should also start with Row 1.

What happened in your initial configuration is that, when checking row 1 if it should be highlighted, It checks the value in K2 and C2 so on....

Comment: The first formula worked perfectly, thank you SO much. I exported the information from our database and it will do that with numbers, but I didn't think about that. Now that raises another question though, is it possible to make the formula ignore the rows where columns D through O are completely blank? I just don't have data in them yet so they don't need to be highlighted. If not it's not a big deal. I appreciate what you've done already!

Comment: You can use this: `=AND($K1="",$C1="10",NOT(AND($D1="",$E1="  ",$F1="",$G1="",$H1="",$I1="",$J1="  ",$K1="",$L1="",$M1="",$N1="",$O1="")))`. Note that I noticed your subject code column is not empty. (blank cells has 2whitespaces)

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to help!

Answer (score 0):

The value in column C is a number so you do not need the " marks

You can apply this custom formula to the whole of your sheet.  The row reference is relative meaning it will check each row in turn starting at row 1.

`=AND($K1="",$C1=10)`

Comment: This should have worked, but the data in column C wasn't pulling because it was text and not a number. I appreciate you taking the time to answer me!